# Latex lstlisting, overlapping keywords

Tags: latex, keyword, dtd, lstlisting, xml

I'm using LaTeX for my exam work and I want to use code listings via lstpackage. I've defined two more keywords in "otherkeywords" options: "id" and "identifier". Both words began with "id" and thats the problem. The keywords "identifier" will not be marked as a keywords completely.

[image: dtd_with_own_keywords]

Does anyone has a solution for this problem?

Comment: Does the order in which you define the two new keywords matter?

Comment: No, the order doesn't matter...

Comment: That's a shame.  I was hoping that defining the longer one first might fix the problem.  Sigh.